# .Net Reflector Font Error

Tags: .net, reflector

I have started to use .Net reflector, but the problem is that whenever i try to run Reflector.exe it shows the error that :".Net Reflector has thrown an exception. Font courior New does not support style "Regular". " And the Reflector shuts down.

what should i do?

Comment: What platform/OS etc? and do you have a custom font (i.e. have you replaced the system font)? In any event, it sounds like a support issue for redgate...

Comment: i am using windows 7. No i have not replaced system font deliberitly. Do not know if it had been changed without my consent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. My courier Font was corrupted. I installed the font and all was set.